# What is the difference between gifts of healing and the working of miracles? 1 Corinthians 12

Tags: 1-corinthians, pneumatology, spiritual-gifts, miracle, healing

1 Corinthians 12 (ESV):

> 4 Now there are varieties of gifts, but the same Spirit; 5 and there are varieties of service, but the same Lord; 6 and there are varieties of activities, but it is the same God who empowers them all in everyone. 7 To each is given the manifestation of the Spirit for the common good. 8 For to one is given through the Spirit the utterance of wisdom, and to another the utterance of knowledge according to the same Spirit, 9 to another faith by the same Spirit, **to another gifts of healing** by the one Spirit, 10 **to another the working of miracles**, to another prophecy, to another the ability to distinguish between spirits, to another various kinds of tongues, to another the interpretation of tongues. 11 All these are empowered by one and the same Spirit, who apportions to each one individually as he wills.
>
> [...]
>
> 27 Now you are the body of Christ and individually members of it. 28 And God has appointed in the church first apostles, second prophets, third teachers, **then miracles, then gifts of healing**, helping, administrating, and various kinds of tongues. 29 Are all apostles? Are all prophets? Are all teachers? **Do all work miracles?** 30 **Do all possess gifts of healing?** Do all speak with tongues? Do all interpret? 31 But earnestly desire the higher gifts.

What is the difference between gifts of healing and the working of miracles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best example is probably Jesus' first and second miracles:

1. John 2:1-11 - Jesus turned water into wine - a miracle that did not involve healing.
2. John 4:43-54 - Jesus heals an Official's son - a miracle of healing.

Note that in John 6 we have another miracle of Jesus that did not involve healing - feeding the 5000 people.

Thus, there are miracles that do not involve healing someone.  Here are a few more:

- John 6:16-24 - Jesus walks on water
- Luke 5:1-11 - the miraculous catch of fish
- John 21:11 - another miraculous catch of fish
- Matt 17:24-27 - the miraculous coin the fish's mouth
- Matt 15:32-39 - feeding the 4000
- Matt 21:18-22 - the fig tree cursed
- Ex 7, 8, 9, 10, etc - the 10 plagues
- Ex 14 - crossing the red sea
- Ex 16 - manna
- Ex 17 - water from the rock

... and so forth.  Thus, miracle workings do not need to involve healing.